# Random variables in estimators

Tags: statistics

As I am a beginner, I am confused with how random variables come into play in estimators i.e.
For example, while estimating mean, the estimator used is[image]

where all Xi's are random variables. But in real data, it is just a constant. How can this be possible?

Can anyone please help me out..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no random variables in real data. There are only constants. You use random variables to model what you might get from a random source, so if you treat your data as coming from a random source, in this case say $X_k$ are independent and come from the same random source (identically distributed), then you can take their average, which would be yet another random variable. If someone else took another $n$ samples from the same source, he would get a different average. Estimators are used to model a means of estimating some unknown constant. When you apply the estimator to real data, what you have is an estimate of the unknown constant, not the estimator. The distribution of your estimator tells you the complete information about the possible estimates. If the estimator has a mean of $m$, it means that the expected value of the estimate you will get is $m$. So ideally you want your estimator to have a mean that is equal to the unknown constant (in which case the estimator is called unbiased), and a small variance.

Comment: **so if you treat your data as coming from a random source, in this case say Xk are independent and come from the same random source (identically distributed)**

Can you help this out?

Comment: "independent" means the probability that one is a certain value is the same whether you know the value of the others or not. These concepts should have been well explained in any textbook introducing probability, which you should learn before learning statistics.

Comment: @Gowtham: It's not so simple because any treatment of probability will have to be axiomatic at some level since there is no way to demonstrate any true random variables in the real world. A bag of balls out of which you draw one cannot honestly be said to be a truly random source, because you are actually deciding which particular ball to draw out; the balls don't switch with one another randomly when you are not looking.

Comment: So.. For calculating the confidence interval(CI) of population mean it is 
CI = (**X(bar)** - critical value * standard error, **X(bar)** +critical value * standard error).
In this case **X(bar)** is a random variable..right?
But while solving we take only the mean of the given sample.

Comment: @Gowtham: Yes only if $n$ is sufficiently large so that the conditions of the central limit theorem are satisfied. $\overline{X}$ as you wrote in your question is indeed a random variable, and so is the interval you wrote in your comment, let's call it $C$! But when you apply it to data, the confidence interval you get is just one single 'draw' from $C$. Notice that it could be completely off.. If you use $95%$ confidence level, it means that you **expect** that $5%$ of the time your confidence interval **will not** include the population mean, and you can't tell **when** that $5%$ occurs.

Comment: So is it **legitimate** to use mean of the given sample as X(bar)?

Comment: @Gowtham: No it's not legitimate. It's best to always define everything to have one and only one meaning. Conventionally we use capital letters for random variables and small letters for values such as constants or samples. So we could define $\overline{X}$ (to get it type `$\overline{X}$`) as the estimator and given samples $(x_k)$ we usually define $\overline{x}$ as the mean of the sample.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning $\overline{X}$. But I have seen many problems solving using the mean of the sample($\overline{x}$)

Comment: @Gowtham: It depends on what you mean by "solve". As I said, in the real world all you have is real data which are not random variables. Assuming it is accurate to model them by random variables, you then develop the mathematical tools such as estimators and theorems about them. Finally when we apply them we have to remember all the assumptions made and what we can actually conclude.

Comment: @Gowtham: We use confidence intervals to try to guess unknown constants that we can't directly measure. Taking one sample gives us one 95% confidence interval. But if 100 people do the same experiment, we **expect** around 5 of them to get a 95% confidence interval that does not include the true value. So how do we know we are not one of those? We can't.